# Is it possible to prevent this kind of first chance exception

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

This is the code which is generating the issue (while debugging with the options to stop on CLR Exceptions):

```
private static XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.Print.PrinterInfo));
```

And this is the exception

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Model.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It's annoying because for debugging purpose I often need to enable stop on CLR Exception but I don't like being stopped on this specific one...

Comment: Is that it trying to tell you that you actually dont have a printer installed?

Comment: No.. I have many. I think the class XmlSerializer looks for a DLL to deserialize the object  Model.Print.PrinterInfo. So it looks for a Model.XmlSerializers but it doesn't find and throws an exception (which is handled, but this behavior is a bit weird).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but I think you won't like it.

You can use `sgen` to generate the `Model.XmlSerializers` assembly, which you can include in your project. That will solve the exception.

What .NET actually does is this:

- Create an `XmlSerializer`;
- Check if there is a serializer for the specific assembly (your exception);
- If not, generate one on the fly;
- Load the assembly, either the generated one or the exising assembly;
- Use the serializer assembly to serialize and deserialize the XML.

As you can see the problem is in step 2. This all happens in the background and the first change exception can't be prevented unless you provide it with an assembly. The plus side is: you gain a little performance by not generating the serialization assembly on the fly.

Comment: Exactly that's what we are using too. You can call sgen in a post-build event.
You can find more details to sgen on the microsoft pages: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/billwert/2008/02/23/use-of-sgen-exe-to-avoid-common-xmlserializer-performance-pitfalls/

Comment: Thanks.. isn't a mistake by the framework to handle a file search which is missing 99,99% of times through an exception? Is there any other way to say to the debugger: never catch this stupid exception?

Comment: Other than not checking the 'is exception thrown', but 'is exception unhandled', no. And the design decision is somewhat okay since you can influence finding the assembly using the `AssemblyResolve` handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is the AssemblyResolve handler? Can I set: "don't search for the assembly"?

Comment: More on the handler [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows you to use custom code to find assemblies (and even download them from somewhere else for example).